# Created a background for my test game, yet the screen updates badly

Tags: python, animation, pygame, sprite

My RPG code:
    import pygame, sys
    from pygame.locals import *
    pygame.init()

```
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("nq-rotmg.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

FPS = 30
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

pywindow = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption('God of the Mad Realm')
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

background = pygame.image.load("Background.jpg")
pywindow.blit(background, (0, 0))
pygame.display.flip()

rogueImg = pygame.image.load('Rogue.png')

roguex = 10
roguey = 10
pygame.key.set_repeat(10, 10)

while True: 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys_pressed[K_LEFT]:
        roguex -= 3

    if keys_pressed[K_RIGHT]:
        roguex += 3

    if keys_pressed[K_UP]:
        roguey -= 3

    if keys_pressed[K_DOWN]:
        roguey += 3

    pywindow.blit(rogueImg, (roguex, roguey))
    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Screenshot of the problem:
[image: screenshot of the problem]

It just gives me this interesting white pixelated background...
Thank you for all and any help!

Comment: How did you insert that picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent the white parts of the image to be displayed by setting the image's colorkey:

```
rogueImg = pygame.image.load('Rogue.png')
rogueImg.set_colorkey((255,255,255))#sets the colorkey to white
```

By the way: For a long time I have had speed problems with pygame using big images.

So in general it is a good idea to convert an image before blitting it:

```
background = pygame.image.load("Background.jpg")
background = background.convert()
```

I hope my ideas will help you a bit.

Answer (score 0):

In your main loop (`while True` loop), you just need to blit the background image before the image of the rogue.  So right before you do

```
pywindow.blit(rogueImg, (roguex, roguey))
```

you should do

```
pywindow.blit(background, (0, 0))
```

The issue is that as your code is, the backgound is getting drawn once.   When you put your sprite on top of the background, you need to redraw the background.

Comment: When I do this I get a black screen and when I press a key it says: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Character.py", line 45, in <module>
    pywindow.blit(background(0, 0))
TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable

Comment: Looks like you're missing a comma there: it's `pywindow.blit(background, (0,0))`; notice the comma after "background".

Comment: Ok so now it is a little cleaner but when I move the white thing still happens every once in a while and then goes away...

Comment: I see that you've got `WHITE = (255, 255, 255)` in your code here. Is that getting used somewhere that you haven't posted?  I think you might be `blit`ting the color somewhere, and that's why you're seeing what you're seeing.

Comment: I got rid of the WHITE and it remained the same. It seems that when I press two keys at the same time or only move left or right, the white appears.

Comment: My next guess is that you need to check your indentation carefully...  maybe something is under an `if` statement that shouldn't be? e.g. you may be blitting the background image only on K_DOWN, which wouldn't be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your updating your background. Put this in the while loop.

```
pywindow.blit(background,(0,0))
```

(Before the bliting of the rogue.)

Hope this helps!